# teach me the pandas dataframe way to do this?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm struggling to convert from a spreadsheet to Python using Pandas Data Frames.

I have some raw data:

```
Date        Temperature
12/4/2003   100
12/5/2003   101
12/8/2003   100
12/9/2003   102
12/10/2003  101
12/11/2003  100
12/12/2003  99
12/15/2003  98
12/16/2003  97
12/17/2003  96
12/18/2003  95
12/19/2003  96
12/22/2003  97
12/23/2003  98
12/24/2003  99
12/26/2003  100
12/29/2003  101
```

In a spreadsheet, I am following a trend based on a %monitor. Think of it as a rolling average but based on %.

Output from spreadsheet:

```
date         temp   monitor   trend        change_in_trend
12/4/2003    100    97.00      warming      false
12/5/2003    101    97.97      warming      false
12/8/2003    100    97.97      warming      false
12/9/2003    102    98.94      warming      false
12/10/2003   101    98.94      warming      false
12/11/2003   100    98.94      warming      false
12/12/2003    99    98.94      warming      false
12/15/2003    98    98.94      cooling      true
12/16/2003    97    98.94      cooling      false
12/17/2003    96    98.88      cooling      false
12/18/2003    95    97.85      cooling      false
12/19/2003    96    97.85      cooling      false
12/22/2003    97    97.85      cooling      false
12/23/2003    98    97.85      warming      true
12/24/2003    99    97.85      warming      false
12/26/2003   100    97.85      warming      false
12/29/2003   101    97.97      warming      false
```

Assumptions:

```
percent_monitor = .03
warming_factor = 1 - percent_monitor
cooling_factor = 1 + percent_monitor
```

In my spreadsheet, I setup the columns in the first row as:

```
monitor = temp * warming_factor
trending = warming
change_in_trend = false
```

All remaining rows are derived based on current and previous row's column values.

monitor column logic:

```
if temp > prev_monitor:
    if temp > prev_temp:
        if temp * warming_factor > prev_monitor:
            monitor = temp*warming_factor
        else:
            monitor = prev_monitor
    else:
        monitor = prev_monitor
else:
    if temp < prev_monitor:
        if temp * cooling_factor < prev_monitor:
            monitor = temp * cooling_factor
        else:
            monitor = prev_monitor
    else:
        monitor = prev_monitor
```

trending column logic:

```
if temp > prev_monitor:
    trending = warming
else:
    trending = cooling
```

change in trend column logic:

```
if current_trend - previous_trend:
    change_in_trend = false
else:
    change in trend = true
```

I was able to iterate through a dataframe and apply the logic with no problem. However, performance is horrible over thousands of rows.

I've been trying to do this in a more 'pandas' like way but have failed in every attempt.

Without embarrassing myself by pasting my code attempts, is there anyone that could offer me some help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is long but reads fine. Please consider a new title though that actually pinpoints the issue you're trying to solve. That way it might be searchable in future for others facing the same issue.

Comment: Are you *positive* your monitor column is correct?

Comment: Spreadsheet is correct, yes. My pseudocode of the logic could be flawed. If it would be helpful, I could paste the actual formulas.

Comment: Yes, please give the formulas :)

Comment: `=IF(ISBLANK(B8),"",IF(B8>C7,IF(B8>B7,IF(SUM(B8*$C$2)>C7,SUM(B8*$C$2),C7),C7),IF(B8<C7,IF(SUM(B8*$C$3)<C7,SUM(B8*$C$3),C7),C7))`

Comment: Is this a rolling operation? Like do you use intermediate results in the calculations?

Comment: `=IF(ISBLANK(B8),"",IF(B8>C8,"warming","cooling"))`

Comment: `=IF(D8<>D7,"true","false")`

Comment: Yes, sort of rolling. The goal is to trap for temperature crossing over/above the %monitor.

Comment: if you graph that sample, it will make more sense visually.

Comment: how slow is too slow? how long does it take to do, for example, 5000 rows? What speed would the 5000 rows have to take for you to be satisfied with your code's performance?

Comment: Processed 46620 rows
Time elapsed (hh:mm:ss.ms) 0:00:44.503049

Comment: Thanks! and what does `if current_trend - previous_trend:` mean for your change in column logic? is that `if current_trend != previous_trend:` ?

Comment: Spreadsheet is immediate. I've been trying to do dataframe function mapping to get the same result. Maybe I've bit off more than I can handle. Sorry if this is too big of a question.

Comment: that's a typo, should read `if current_trend = previous_trend: then false` (no signal)

Comment: Are you set on converting this to python through pandas in particular or are other avenues okay as long as they are performant?

Comment: I am flexible, the dataframe seemed at first like the right tool. Having spent some hours grinding on this already, now I don't know. Thoughts?

Comment: If you just want it in python, I think it might make your life easier if you used normal python functionality. I added my attempt as an answer to this question. Hopefully it works for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are looking to just move this over to Python and are not set up Pandas in particular, I went for a non-pandas approach. I used your example rows and did `47124` rows in `0.182` seconds.

Pandas is really good and intuitive for some use cases, but can get extremely slow for iteration. [This page](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) explains some of the slower uses of Pandas one of them mainly being index iteration. A pandas-ey way to do this would to be to take advantage of `5. Vectorization with NumPy arrays`, but your use case seems straightforward enough that this might be overkill and might not be worth it (given that your name is PythonNoob).

For the sake of both clarity and speed, a simple use of the more basic python functions can get you the speed you want.

First I set up the constants

```
percent_monitor = .03
warming_factor = 1 - percent_monitor
cooling_factor = 1 + percent_monitor
```

Then (for ease of use, there are cleaner ways to do this but this is very clear) I set the names of the columns corresponding to the column values:

```
DATE = 0
TEMP = 1
MONITOR = 2
TRENDING = 3
CHANGE_IN_TREND = 4
```

Then I pulled out your monitor code in its own function (and cleaned up the `if`-statements a bit:

```
def calculate_monitor(prev_monitor, current_temp, prev_temp):
     if (current_temp > prev_monitor) and (current_temp > prev_temp) and (current_temp * warming_factor) > prev_monitor:
            return current_temp * warming_factor
        elif (current_temp < prev_monitor) and ((current_temp * cooling_factor) < prev_monitor):
            return current_temp * cooling_factor
        else:
            return prev_monitor
```

Finally, I read in the code and processed it:

```
data = [] # I am going to append everything to this
with open('weather_data.csv') as csv_file:
    previous_row = None
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=' ')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        cleaned_row = list(filter(None, row))
        if line_count == 0:
            # first row is column -- I am leaving it blank you can do whatever you want with it
            line_count += 1
        elif line_count == 1: # this is the first line
            previous_row = cleaned_row + [float(cleaned_row[TEMP]) * warming_factor, "warming", False]
            data.append(previous_row)
            line_count += 1
        else:
            monitor = calculate_monitor(float(previous_row[MONITOR]), float(cleaned_row[TEMP]), float(previous_row[TEMP]))
            current_trend = 'warming' if float(cleaned_row[TEMP]) > float(previous_row[MONITOR]) else 'cooling'
            change_in_trend = False if current_trend != previous_row[CHANGE_IN_TREND] else True
            previous_row = cleaned_row + [monitor, current_trend, change_in_trend]
            data.append(previous_row)
            line_count += 1
```

That will get you the speed you need. If you want to convert this to a pandas dataframe at the end you can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'temp', 'monitor', 'current_trend', 'change_in_trend'])
```

Comment: That's really awesome!

Processed 46620 rows
Time elapsed (hh:mm:ss.ms) 0:00:03.953717

Really shows how inefficient my iterative loop is.

Many many thanks! Where do I send the check to?

Comment: I’m glad this helped! Would appreciate if you marked this as the official answer to your question and gave this an upvote to help other who might have the same question as you.

Comment: @PythonNoob you were probably doing indexed iteration over a dataframe, and that is *extremely* inefficient, because there's a lot of overhead per indexing operation (meant to work on whole dataframes). Even worse, you may have inadvertently mixed the iterative and vectorized methods to produce the worst of both worlds. You can get comparable performance iterating the dataframe if you make sure to loop with `itertuples`. That returns an iterator over the rows of the dataframe as `collections.namedtuple` objects. And you can implement this solution in those terms and keep working with your df.

Comment: I was using `for idx, row in df.iterrows():` then, walking through my decision tree as best as I knew how. I had not seen nor considered the approach that Aur gave me. I am back on track now thanks to Aur!

Comment: Aur, in that link you shared, where they "peek under the hood", what utility is providing those timings? I would be curious to see just how bad my coding is.

Comment: `%%timeis` is a Jupyter notebook-specific command called `timeit` (https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit).  If you aren't using Jupyter, you can use the the `timeit` module here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html